# Turn off SQLCMD query output

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

I am executing a bunch of SQL scripts using `SQLCMD`, and redirecting the output to a log file using the `-o` switch. How do I turn off the output of SELECT queries? Errors, if any, should still be written to the log file, as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to log only errors, log by redirecting `STDERR` rather than by using the `-o` switch:

```
SQLCMD -S server -d database -E -r0 -Q "select 1" 2> error.log
```

**update**
Added that the `-r0` switch must be set to redirect errors to `STDERR`

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Also, how do I not display the query output on the console? Is there a way to redirect `STDOUT` to null?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sqlcmd -S server -d database -E -r0 -Q "select 1" 1> NUL  2> NUL
```

`-Q` allows you to specify your query.

`1>` is for the stdout. You can use `1> logs.txt` instead to write the output into a file.

`2>` is for the stderr. You can use `2> errors.txt` instead to write the errors into a file.

Further reading is available on [sqlcmd reference from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017).